# php-MQTT/client library TLS issue with certbot certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am trying to load messages from my Mosquitto broker which is secured with certbot certificates (and tested via MQTTX) but after many hours trying to make php-MQTT /client library and searching a lot around the web and asking chat GPT I have to admit defeat until know. The various example I have found are for local use or self-signed certificate.
I can connect to my broker through Javascript and paho library but I really would like to do most of the work server side: store payloads in a MYSQL database, load messages and prepare them to then use javascript for my front end.
Suggestion on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. Also if I am going the wrong direction using php libraries to work with MQTT I appreciate. I am quite new at the whole MQTT and API world.

Here is my current setup using PHP 8.1:
I checked that the file permission and the server can access them (edit 2023-03-26 modified to only use the CA file)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient;
use PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings;

// Define your MQTT broker host, port, and TLS port.
$host = 'www.example.com';
$port = 1883;
$tlsPort = 8883;

// Define the path to your certificate files.
$caFile = '/etc/mosquitto/certs/chain.pem';
$keyPassphrase = null;

// Define your MQTT authorization credentials.
$username = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxx';


// Create and configure the connection settings.
$connectionSettings = (new ConnectionSettings)
    ->setUseTls(true)
    ->setTlsCertificateAuthorityFile($caFile)
    ->setUsername($username)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ->setTlsVerifyPeerName(false);  //I tried true as well no difference 

// Create the MQTT client instance.
$client = new MqttClient($host, $port, 'php-mqtt-client');

// Enable error logging
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_log', 'php_errors.log');

// Set the error reporting level to show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Set up an error handler to log errors
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    error_log("Error [$errno]: $errstr in $errfile on line $errline");
});
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


// Connect to the MQTT broker using the configured connection settings.
$client->connect($connectionSettings);

// Subscribe to a topic.
$client->subscribe('topic', function ($topic, $message, $retained, $matchedWildcards) {
    echo sprintf("Received message on topic [%s]: %s\n", $topic, $message);
}, 0);

$client->loop(true);

// Disconnect from the MQTT broker.
$client->disconnect();
```

The error log returns this:

```
[26-Mar-2023 19:57:55 UTC] Error [2]: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/www.example.com/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php on line 266
[26-Mar-2023 19:57:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\ConnectingToBrokerFailedException: [2000] Establishing a connection to the MQTT broker failed: TLS error [UNKNOWN:1]: Unknown error in /var/www/www.example.com/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php:284
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/www.example.com/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(158): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->establishSocketConnection()
#1 /var/www/www.example.com/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(144): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->connectInternal()
#2 /var/www/www.example.com/test.php(56): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->connect()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/www.example.com/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php on line 284
```

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to use SSL client identification? (Have you told mosquitto to require a client cert?)

Comment: Hmmm. No indeed. I just assumed I had to to have secured connection

Comment: Then remove all the code using the key file, certified and keypassword

Comment: You are trying to connect to a non-TLS port (1883) with TLS enabled. Mosquitto is not a fan of this and will close the connection. You might have a look into your Mosquitto logs as well. @hardillb is correct that you should first enable an additional TLS port in your Mosquitto config or replace the non-TLS port configuration entirely, if you want to allow secure connections only.

Comment: You are still explicitly telling it to use port 1883 not 8883 even though you have told the client to use TLS. The client will NOT change the port you have explicitly told it to use.

Answer (score 0):

So after much investigation I discovered a few things: first my certificate was wrong which blocked a TLS connection. So I first tried without certificate and it worked fine in Visual Studio Code but as soon as I uploaded to my server I always had Error 500 issues. Two things were happening. I had conflicting PHP version on my Ubuntu server and I am not handy enough with Ubuntu to clean it all properly. As I have nothing else running on the server at the moment I decided to reinstall it all with Ubuntu 22.04 and PHP 8.2. I know have the whole thing working with this code

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/shared/config.php';

use PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings;
use PhpMqtt\Client\Examples\Shared\SimpleLogger;
use PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\MqttClientException;
use PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient;
use Psr\Log\LogLevel;

// Create an instance of a PSR-3 compliant logger. For this example, we will 
also use the logger to log exceptions.
$logger = new SimpleLogger(LogLevel::INFO);

// Define your MQTT authorization credentials.
$username = 'name';
$password = 'password';

try {
    // Create a new instance of an MQTT client and configure it to use the 
shared broker host and port.
    $client = new MqttClient(MQTT_BROKER_HOST, MQTT_BROKER_TLS_PORT, 'test- 
publisher', MqttClient::MQTT_3_1, null, $logger);

    // Create and configure the connection settings as required.
    $connectionSettings = (new ConnectionSettings)
        ->setUseTls(true)
        ->setTlsSelfSignedAllowed(true)
        ->setTlsClientCertificateFile("client.crt")
        ->setTlsClientCertificateKeyFile("client.key")
        ->setTlsClientCertificateKeyPassphrase("passphrase")
        ->setUsername($username)
        ->setPassword($password);

    // Connect to the broker with the configured connection settings and with a 
clean session.
    $client->connect($connectionSettings, true);

    // Publish the message 'Hello world!' on the topic 'foo/bar/baz' using QoS 
0.
    //$client->publish('foo/bar/baz', 'Hello world!', 
MqttClient::QOS_AT_MOST_ONCE);

    // Subscribe to a topic.
$client->subscribe('sensor/data', function ($topic, $message){ //}, $retained, 
$matchedWildcards) {
    //echo sprintf("Received message on topic [%s]: %s\n", $topic, $message);

        // Decode the JSON message into a PHP object.
        $data = json_decode($message);

        // Extract the individual values from the object and print them to the 
console.
        echo sprintf("Received message on topic [%s]:\n", $topic);
        echo "Temperature: " . $data->temperature . "\n";
        echo "Humidity: " . $data->humidity . "\n";
        echo "Latitude: " . $data->latitude . "\n";
        echo "Longitude: " . $data->longitude . "\n";
        echo "Date: " . $data->date . "/" . $data->month . "/" . $data->year . 
        "\n";
        echo "Time: " . $data->hours . ":" . $data->minutes . ":" . $data- 
        >seconds . "\n";
    
}, 0);

$client->loop(true);


    // Gracefully terminate the connection to the broker.
    $client->disconnect();
} catch (MqttClientException $e) {
    // MqttClientException is the base exception of all exceptions in the 
library. Catching it will catch all MQTT related exceptions.
    $logger->error('Connecting with TLS or publishing with QoS 0 failed. An 
exception occurred.', ['exception' => $e]);
}
```

It works perfectly and print in the terminal the messages commming in.
Once upladed I can access the php from a browser, it shows nicely that the connection is secured but then nothing until something happends in the connection and then it prints on the screen every messages in the background. I am pretty sure this comes from php being server side and I need to write some javascript to update the front end properly.

I hope this might help somebody else.